# Python 3: Input in cmd to return functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, input

I'm currently working my way through "Learn Python the Hard Way" and got to the first exercise about functions. It's simply creating a few functions and printing them out like in the previous examples in the book`.

Code:

```
def print_two(*args):
    arg1, arg2 = args
    print("arg1: %r, arg2: %r" % (arg1, arg2))

def print_two_again(arg1, arg2):
    print("arg1: %r, arg2: %r" % (arg1, arg2))

def print_one(arg1):
    print("arg1: %r" % (arg1))

def print_none():
    print("I got nothing.")

print_two("Zed","Shaw")
print_two_again("Zed","Shaw")
print_one("First!")
print_none()
```

Output in cmd:

```
C:\Users\[USER]\Google Drive\Python\Learn Python the Hard Way>python ex18.py
arg1: 'Zed', arg2: 'Shaw'
arg1: 'Zed', arg2: 'Shaw'
arg1: 'First!'
I got nothing.
```

I want to play around a bit with this, so instead of just giving me the above four lines when I run it, I want to be able to input the name of the function and then return the result. I tried with the following, but maybe I just don't understand how Python works?

```
x = input("> ")
print(x)
```

I'm not quite sure on the terminology but it would give me the following in cmd:

```
C:\Users\[USER]\Google Drive\Python\Learn Python the Hard Way>python ex18.py
> print_none()  # This is something I write myself
I got nothing.
```

Comment: Return a result of a method call?

Comment: I tried to change the question, does it make sense now?

Comment: Yeah, so you'd like to specify a method name and then execute it and print a result to the console.

Comment: Yeah, that´s what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Thank you, I realized that I should have posted the answer below instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question might have been a little vague, but I found a solution myself. What I was looking for was the "import" function of the script into cmd, which then allows input the commands and return the lines that were hardcoded before:

```
C:\Users\[User]\Google Drive\Python\Learn Python the Hard Way>python
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on 
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ex18
arg1: 'Zed', arg2: 'Shaw'
arg1: 'Zed', arg2: 'Shaw'
arg1: 'First!'
I got nothing.
>>> ex18.print_none()
I got nothing.
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_two_again(arg1, arg2):
    print("arg1: %r, arg2: %r" % (arg1, arg2))

def print_one(arg1):
    print("arg1: %r" % (arg1))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = input("F name:")
    eval(x)
```

Example:

```
/home/denis/zmqPG/bin/python /home/denis/PycharmProjects/useless/so2.py
F name:print_one(5)
arg1: 5
```